# Validar data annotations solo cuando se pulsa el submit del formulario

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net-core

Tengo un formulario de Login y me gustaría saber como se puede hacer para validar los campos, solo cuando se pulse el botón del formulario en la parte del cliente antes de enviar la información al servidor

Ahora mismo me lo válida también cuando el campo pierde el foco o pones un valor incorrecto en el campo.

El modelo está definido de la siguiente manera:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.CampoObligatorio))]
    [RegularExpression(Constants.Constants.Regex.RegexCIF, ErrorMessage = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.CIFIncorrecto))]
    [Display(Name = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.CIF))]        
    public string DniCif { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.CampoObligatorio))]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.FormatoIncorrecto))]
    [Display(Name = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.CorreoElectronico))]
    public string CorreoElectronico { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.CampoObligatorio))]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.CaracteristicasPasswordMsg), MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.Password))]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.ConfirmaPassword))]
    [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = nameof(SharedResource.Resources.PasswordNoCoincidentesMsg))] 
    [NotMapped]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

}

Y en la parte HTML:

```
  <form asp-page="./Signin" id="idFormLogin" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">

                @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }).ToHtmlString()))
                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginModel.DniCif, new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginModel.DniCif, new {@class = "form-control", @maxlength = "11" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginModel.DniCif, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginModel.CorreoElectronico, new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginModel.CorreoElectronico, new {@class = "form-control", @type = "email" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginModel.CorreoElectronico, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginModel.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.LoginModel.Password, new {  @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginModel.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-btn" type="submit">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString(nameof(Resources.SharedResource.Resources.IniciarSesionBtn))</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

¿Como se puede hacer la validación solo al pulsar el botón? 
Me da igual si es con Javascript o no

Gracias

Comment: Con "al pulsar el botón" te refieres a **antes** del submit (en el cliente), o **después** del submit (al llegar al servidor).

Comment: En la parte del cliente, perdón por no especificarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu proyecto es del tipo ASP.NET Core, la validación por defecto que se aplica es ***jquery-validation***, en conjunción con los *DataAnnotations* del Modelo y los `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` de la Vista.

En tu caso podrías modificar el comportamiento por defecto de *jquery-validation* para que no se valide al introducir los datos o al perder el foco en un control.

La solución estaría en incluir el siguiente Script en tu Vista:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({
         onkeyup: false,
         focusInvalid: false,
         onfocusout: false
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfecto, me ha funcionado como quería. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Sergio:  Estupendo!, recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han servido para solucionar tu pregunta.